# Kolmogorov-Forward-Equation with Entry and Exit

Tags: macroeconomics, continuous-time

I'll try to ask this question in the most simplistic environment possible, so lets think about a household that can consume and save. After some cumbersome work, we have solved for the optimal savings policy, and know that the change of assets, given his assets $a$, is given by $s(a) = \dot a(a)$.

Denoting with $g(a, t)$ the density of households with assets at level $a$ given time $t$, I can compute the Kolmogorov Forward Equation for the distribution of assets:

$$ \partial_t g(a, t) = - \partial_a [s(a,t)g(a,t)]$$

Where I followed the methodology of [Achdou et al, Appendix A3](http://www.princeton.edu/~moll/HACT.pdf): First compute the CDF $G(a, t)$, and then use that $g(a,t) = \partial_t G(a,t)$.

However, now assume that we have birth and death of households. Most importantly, I don't want there to be a constant death rate, but let's make the death rate conditional on the asset level: $d(a,t)$ - and let's denote birth by $b(a,t)$. Intuitively, I'd think that the new KFE would be given by

$$ \partial_t g(a, t) = - \partial_a [s(a,t)g(a,t)] - d(a,t)g(a,t) + b(a,t)$$

Intuition aside, how can I derive the correct KFE that allows for death rates and birth from the scratch?

Comment: Hey, this is really a great question! I can't find any answer. By any chance, you have some idea of how to derive KFE now? I'd really appreciate it.